# Spark is unable to handle a particular date format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to cast multiple date formats from string type field using Pyspark. When I am using below date format it is working fine.

```py
def custom_to_date(col):
    formats = ("MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/yy","dd/M/yyyy")
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, f) for f in formats])
    
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, to_date
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "01/22/2010"), (2, "2018-12-01")], ("id", "dt"))
df.withColumn("pdt", custom_to_date("dt")).show()
```

Above code gives the correct output.
But when I use the month in single digit as below, the code fails.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "01/22/2010"), (2, "2018-12-1"),(3,"24/7/2006")], ("id", "dt"))
```

I got the below error message.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException:
  Job aborted due to stage failure:
    Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
      Lost task 2.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 10) (10.13.82.55 executor 0): 
        org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: 
        [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] 
        You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
```

Comment: If you have an additional date format add an additional date format?

Comment: in date formatting, `MM` != `M`

Comment: I have corrected the example. I am trying to use single month digit, it is giving error. I have added that format as well.@DaveNewton

Comment: @samkart yes I have tried using dd/M/yyyy, it is not working

Comment: Doesn't `dd` explicitly specify a two-digit number? If that's not what you want you need to either change the existing format, or add an additional one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adding an answer since the comments and others answer doesn't cover the behaviour. The solution is not to add new formats. Since the formats itself can be better defined.*

with spark 3.0 `M` supports `01, 1. January, Jan`.
So you don't need `MM`

spark reference - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

```
def custom_to_date(col):
    formats = ("M/d/yyyy", "yyyy-M-d", "d/M/y", "M/y")
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, f) for f in formats])
    
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, to_date
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "01/22/2010"), (2, "2018-12-1"),(3,"12/2023")], ("id", "dt"))
df.withColumn("pdt", custom_to_date("dt")).show()
```

Results -

[image]

Alternatively, if you want legacy behavior then you can use

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")`
or
`spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")`

Comment: If I use 12/23 instead of 12/2023 it gives me 0023-12-01. It it is unable to interpret 23 as 2023.

Comment: Hm I see as per documentation it should give 2023, `Year: The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used. If the count of letters is two, then a reduced two digit form is used. For printing, this outputs the rightmost two digits. For parsing, this will parse using the base value of 2000, resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive
` - from the docs

Not sure of this behaviour but can be solved writing YY

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to advance the patterns with single digit, otherwise it will fail when it tries to parse with the two digits pattern

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, to_date

def custom_to_date(col):
    formats = ("MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-d", "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/yy")
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, f) for f in formats])


df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "01/22/2010"), (2, "2018-12-01"), (3, "01/22/2010"), (4, "2018-12-1"), (5,"24/7/2006")], ("id", "dt"))

df.withColumn("pdt", custom_to_date("dt")).show()
```

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|        dt|       pdt|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|01/22/2010|2010-01-22|
|  2|2018-12-01|2018-12-01|
|  3|01/22/2010|2010-01-22|
|  4| 2018-12-1|2018-12-01|
|  5| 24/7/2006|2006-07-24|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Could you please let me know why just shuffling the format is resolving the issue?

Comment: Mainly because parsing with the two digits format will match first with the year, but will fail to find the two month digits so it will throw an exception, but trying to parse with the one digit first then the two digits should cover both cases